# Javascript Video Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to Jquery.

I'm trying to pause/play a video by clicking the video itself and also by click a play/pause button. 
Now, I've managed to get it working as desired when the user clicks the video.
But I can't get it to work using the button as well.

This what I've tried so far:

```
$("video").trigger("play");//for auto play
$('video, #pausebutton').click(function() {
if ($('video').hasClass('pause')) {
 $("video").trigger("play");
 $(this).removeClass('pause');
 $("#artwork").removeClass('fadein')
 $(this).addClass('play');
 $("#pausing").html("&#9616;&#9616;");
} else {
 $("video").trigger("pause");
 $(this).removeClass('play');
 $(this).addClass('pause');
 $("#artwork").addClass('fadein');
 $("#pausing").html("&#9658;");
}
});
```

The pause button does actually pause the video, but it doesn't resume play when clicked for a second time. It also ignores the other attributes such as add and removing classes etc. Just to clarify, all these things work when the video is clicked directly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the use of `this` inside the event handler, when the button is clicked `this` is the button, not the video, and the classes are set on the button instead of the video

```
$("video").trigger("play"); //for auto play
$('video, #pausebutton').click(function () {
    if ($('video').hasClass('pause')) {
        $("video").trigger("play");
        $('video').removeClass('pause');
        $("#artwork").removeClass('fadein')
        $('video').addClass('play');
        $("#pausing").html("&#9616;&#9616;");
    } else {
        $("video").trigger("pause");
        $('video').removeClass('play');
        $('video').addClass('pause');
        $("#artwork").addClass('fadein');
        $("#pausing").html("&#9658;");
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fLyx7arL/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't know that. Why is the script working as desired when clicking the video directly if the pause and play events cannot be triggered by jQuery?

Comment: @benmandv - my bad, it seems you can trigger methods, `trigger` now creates an event and triggers it internally.

Comment: @benmandv - it's the use of `this` inside the event handler, you're adding and removing the class to the video when that is clicked, and the button when that is clicked etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Any idea why the    #pausebutton does not do as desired?